# Byte Array representation. Why are there characters not included in the hexadecimal representation? "<,],_,..."

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, hex, byte, special-characters

I have a byte array saved on redis, which I can see printed as

```
\xa3H\xbc\xc8\\<;\xf4-\xf9
```

According to my research, `\x` stands for: "what follows is a hexadecimal representation" of a byte.

So, for example, `\xbc` stands for: we have the hexadecimal number `BC`, which is the number 11 * 16 + 12 * 1. This is due to the fact that in hexadecimal we have the 16 digits: 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, A, B, C, D, E, F (so in this case B = 11, C = 12).

But why do we have other digits other than these 16? Why do we have the `H`? Why do we have double slash `\\`? Why do we have the symbols `<;`, `-` in this particular case?

Comment: Because they're printable ASCII characters, so it shows e.g. `H` instead of `\x48`. The values of the rest depend on the encoding (e.g. `b'\xa3H\xbc\xc8\\<;\xf4-\xf9'.decode('ISO-8859-1')` -> `'£H¼È\\<;ô-ù'`).